# LM324N comparator, why does the output not reach v+?

Tags: operational-amplifier, biasing

I am trying to use a LM324N as a comparator. Here is the circuit and the waveforms. As you can see the output does not exceed ~3.8V, why does it not go to 5V? Am I incorrect in expecting the output to reach 5V?
Also note that I initially did it without the feedback resistors and just an open loop with the same result, then copied their circuit example for a comparator out of the datasheet.

[image: Circuit][image: Waveforms]

Comment: For a more modern alternative with rail-to-rail output swing, see LMV324.

Answer (score 10):

If you look at the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm324.pdf) you’ll see that a drop of 1.2V when the output is high and sourcing even a tiny current such as a few uA is quite typical.

[image]

The reason has to do with the design of the output stage, which you can see in Fig 8.2 — there is an NPN Darlington pair to the positive rail.

Answer (score 3):

From the datasheet marked up, you can use 1k , 10k pullup or lower like 470 for faster slew rates.

[image]

If you want a bandaid solution and do not have any major load current demands, add a pull resistor to suit your needs.  The output impedance of the low side will be < 100 Ohms in current limit mode   and the high side will be your pullup resistor above 3.8V and below that buffered by the Darlington.
[image]

The current limit is by design and measured by forcing the output to max and then shorting it to the other rail to measure current.

A better solution might be a CMOS logic AC coupled with negative feedback often used in the CD4xxx CMOS days decades ago.

Answer (score -2):

The LM324 us very old. If you like its poor high frequency output then use a modern LMV324 that has inputs and outputs that are rail-to-rail. Caution, its max allowed supply is 5.5V.

Comment: This should be a comment , not a answer.